# Umbraco 5 - type or namespace 'AssemblyContainsPlugins' could not be found

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm trying to create plugins for Umbraco 5. I see in all examples mention of the following line to AssemblyInfo.cs, in order to mark an assembly for export:

```
[assembly: AssemblyContainsPlugins]
```

Trouble I'm having is I receive the 'type or namespace' error for AssemblyContainsPlugins and AssemblyContainsPluginsAttribute. I tried googling the names to see what assembly I'm not referencing but can't find it.

Can anyone see what I've missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you missed this using statement:

```
using Umbraco.Cms.Web;
```